# Connect with teams from an Azure Automation with "run as" account

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, azure-automation, azure-authentication

I would like to assign Teams policies from an Azure Automation. For this I use the PowerShell module "MicrosoftTeams" in the current version.

When I log in to Teams with user credential, as shown below, the assignment works.

```
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'Teams-Admin'
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $Cred

# Grant policys
Grant-CsUserPolicyPackage -Identity $mailAddress -PackageName Test
```

However, I want to use the Run-As account to log in, as shown below. When I do that, I get an error.

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection –Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -TenantId $connection.TenantID `
    -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID `
    -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint

# Grant policys
Grant-CsUserPolicyPackage -Identity $mailAddress -PackageName Test
```

The error is as follows:

> Grant-CsUserPolicyPackage : Powershell administered domain is unexpectedly null/empty

The app registry of the "Run-As" account has the Teams administrator and Skype for Business administrator role. In addition, I have delegated "AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "User.Read.All" permissions to Microsoft Graph in the API permissions and "user_impersonation" permissions to Skype and Teams Tenant Admin API.

Comment: Could you please share your teams module version?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT I use the MicrosoftTeams module version 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Principal names is currently not supported. We have backlog item for this but do not have an ETA to share.